# Live plotting in Matlab with slider

Tags: matlab, user-interface, filter, signals

I have a GUI with a graph and a slider. I have a signal and i am applying filter to that signal, the slider will determine the cutt off frequncy of the filter. I want to live plot the signal when the slider is moved.

below is the code of my GUI.

```html
function varargout = gui(varargin)
% GUI MATLAB code for gui.fig
%      GUI, by itself, creates a new GUI or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = GUI returns the handle to a new GUI or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      GUI('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in GUI.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      GUI('Property','Value',...) creates a new GUI or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before gui_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to gui_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help gui

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 16-Jul-2016 17:10:15

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @gui_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @gui_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before gui is made visible.
function gui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to gui (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for gui
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes gui wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = gui_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% --- Executes on slider movement.
function slider1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'Value') returns position of slider
%        get(hObject,'Min') and get(hObject,'Max') to determine range of slider

sliderValue = get(handles.slider1,'Value'); % slider value
 signal = [....] % my signal
 time = [...] % my time

  f = ltiFilter.PT1(); % my another class where i have filter.

  f.fc = slivervalue; % frequncy from slider.
  filtered_signal = f.eval(signal) % applying of filter.

  
% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function slider1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% disp(sprintf(get(hObject,'String')));
%h = uicontrol('style','slider');
%get(handles.slider1,'Value');
%fprintf('%d\n', r);
% hObject    handle to slider1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: slider controls usually have a light gray background.
if isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor',[.9 .9 .9]);
end


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton2.
function pushbutton2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton2 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)


function edit1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: get(hObject,'String') returns contents of edit1 as text
%        str2double(get(hObject,'String')) returns contents of edit1 as a double


% --- Executes during object creation, after setting all properties.
function edit1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to edit1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: edit controls usually have a white background on Windows.
%       See ISPC and COMPUTER.
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end
function axes1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to axes1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    empty - handles not created until after all CreateFcns called

% Hint: place code in OpeningFcn to populate axes1
```

my signal is in function `slider1_Callback` , below is my shown GUI.

[image: GUI]

whenever i move the slider i want the slider value to be fed to "f.fc" and the filtered_signal to be updated and to be plotted automatically. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: because you already assign the slider-value in the callback-function, your problem at this point is updating the plot?

Comment: that and even plotting the plot, i don't know where and how do i plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have calculated the signal with the new cut off frequency you will have to update the plot/axes data:

```
% set the x- and the y-value 
set(handles.axes1, 'XData',filtered_signal.x, 'YData',filtered_signal.y);
% update the handles-structure to store the data
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

also have look at the following examples:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/gui-that-accepts-parameters-and-generates-plots.html

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/automatically-refresh-plot-in-a-guide-gui.html

maybe most of your questions are answered here.

Comment: Thank you! before i try your answer. i just wrote plot(filtered_signal.x,filtered_signal.x) in the slider1_Callback. And this works. can you tell me what's the difference between the two

Comment: The function `plot` draws the data into the current axes of the current figure. Because you only have one figure with one axes-object, the data is drawn into this.